# View not rendering well on some devices

Tags: xcode, uiview, interface-builder

So I have a view which I made using Xcode's InterfaceBuilder. So sadly, not much code to share. But basically the problem is, I see the interface (in both my iPhone 7 and the Simulator) as follows:

[image]

But my client is seeing it like this:

[image]

I am using Xcode 10, the app is made using Swift 4.2 
I've also had the exact same problem using xcode 9.2

Any ideas? It renders well on my simulator and device but it fails on my customers iPhone 7! I couldn't reproduce this bug yet either..Any ideas? Txs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, all the users of this app in the client company were Senior people so they were using the Zoomed feature on their devices, and this messed around with the Layouts. I had to start testing the app with Zoom turned on as well.